# PowerBuilder NULL and Empty variable

Tags: null, powerbuilder

I'm using PowerBuilder and have a problem with the if condition. I want to check if a variable is not null or it is not empty.

So first I have following if condition to test if the variable is null or not:

```
IF IsNull(ls_name) THEN
    messagebox("ls_name", "is null")  //true
else
    messagebox("ls_name", "is not null")
end if
```

From the above condition, I know that ls_name is null. Now I test if its empty or not:

```
if ls_name = "" then
    messagebox ("ls_name", "is empty")
else
    messagebox("ls_name", "is not empty") //true
end if
```

And i get that ls_name is not empty.

Now when I use an if condition to check if ls_name is NOT Null or it is NOT empty, I put the following if condition:

```
IF not IsNull(ls_name) or ls_name <> "" THEN
    messagebox("test", "condition true")
else
    messagebox("test", "condition false")  //this becomes true.
end if
```

It goes to the else part of the condition. Shouldn't the if part become true? Am I writing the if condition wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking of "null" as "unknown" has always gotten me by in understanding how expressions evaluated.

So, when ls_name is null,

```
not IsNull(ls_name) or ls_name <> ""
```

evaluates to

```
NOT TRUE OR UNKNOWN
```

or

```
FALSE OR UNKNOWN
```

Well, for an OR to evaluate to TRUE, at least one condition must be TRUE. That doesn't apply in this case.

The way I usually test for this is:

```
IF NOT (IsNull (ls_name) OR ls_name = "") THEN
```

which, when ls_name is null, resolves to

```
NOT (TRUE OR UNKNOWN)
```

then

```
NOT (TRUE)
```

and

```
FALSE
```

In other words, the variable is "empty".

Good luck,

Terry

Answer (score 1):

Beware of PB manner for testing `if` conditions and null behavior:

- unlike C language, PB is not making lazy evaluation, i.e it always evaluates all the parts of the condition and does not stop at the first false or true part
- null is contagious, in the sense that if a part of a statement returns null, the whole statement becomes null
- a null statement is always false when using `if`

So in your case, it is probable that when ls_name is null the `not IsNull(ls_name)`is evaluating to true, but `ls_name <> ""` is becoming null, thus `true or null` is becoming null and you always going to the `else` part.

I would check in 2 times :

```
if not IsNull(ls_name) then
    if ls_name <> "" then
        //not empty
    else
        //empty
    end if
else
    //null
end if
```

If you need to handle the same code for not empty / not null then you would have to use some kind of boolean flag. I also starting to use the `goto` statement that is handy when dealing with nested `if` statement.

(BTW : NO, `goto`- when used carefully - is not evil ;o)

Comment: GOTO: Aside from my own opinion (I'll try to avoid the phrase "evil relic from the 60's" <g>), a more important opinion is Microsoft's. GOTO isn't supported in .NET, so having it in your PB code means you'll have a fix to make before you move to PB.NET, where it isn't supported because of Microsoft's lack of support. The times, they are a'changin, as should your coding style.

Comment: @Terry: I won't argue too much about `goto` usage, but just to tell, we have a several quite elaborated applications here that are currently in 11.5 classic and would probably upgrade to 12.5 classic but never to .NET due to our custom PBNI extensions. That would require a notable effort to rewrite and that effort will probably never be planned by company brains... I was not aware that .NET does not provides goto, but we do use it with care in C or PB essentially for cleaning purpose in error handling and it is actually helpful. Java lacks it also (even if a goto opcode does exist anyway)...

Comment: FWIW, GoTo *is* supported in C# and Visual Basic, whether there are valid use cases is a matter of opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

Best technique i use for my programs are

> If IsNull(ls_name) THEN ls_name = ""
>
> IF Len(Trim(ls_name)) = 0 THEN
>
> ```
>  ERR  MSG HERE
> ```
>
> END IF

i always set null strings to empty spaces then check if the strings are empty.. it also depends on the scenario you are running